# Which is safer: upgrading to SSD or never touching internals?

Tags: ssd

This is a question about risk.

Solid-state storage drives are believed to generate less heat than mechanical drives. Large variations in temperature are bad for the longevity of notebook computers. Therefore, one may be able to extend the usable lifespan of one's notebook computer by replacing a mechanical drive with a solid-state drive.

The upgrade, however, involves various risks related to electrostatic discharge. Unless one is very careful, one can damage components by touching them improperly.

Assume Jack is a reasonably competent person. He bought a new notebook computer with only mechanical storage. Jack cares only about longevity, not performance. Should he **upgrade to a solid-state drive or leave his computer as it is**?

Comment: You might not know this, but homework is to be done by you. Surprisingly, this site is not dedicated to helping with homework.

Answer (score 3):

If Jack manages to destroy a harddrive when trying to install it, he should never be allowed to touch a screwdriver again.

Not an answer, you say? Well, if he is reasonable compenent in the area of common sense, he should not have a problem upgrading to an SSD disk:

- Don't touch exposed electronics
- Touch the chassis of the computer so he has a neutral charge relative to the machine
- Do not lick any small parts, regardless how tasty they look
- Just to be on the safe side, don't lick any big parts either

For a laptop, SSD should be the winner in terms of longevety, due to the fact that it has no moving parts. For a stationary computer, I would say a good old mechanical drive will do just fine. This, of course, if performance is ignored.

The reason why mechanical drives might be preferable is because SSDs in themselves come with some pitfalls: They have a limited amount of read/write cycles. While modern SSD drives are much more reliable than the first generation of SSD drives, there are some considerations to adress when setting up the system. What these considerations are varies from disk to disk and OS to OS, so that's beyond the scope of this answer. Basically, limiting unecessary reads and writes is the clue.

Comment: Funny response, but don't help this person with their homework.